# Split a list into N parts

Tags: elixir

Given a list, how can I split it into N sub-lists? They don't have necessarily have to be of the equal size. For instance, given 9 elements and split it into N = 3 sub-lists => 3x3. Or into N = 4 sub-lists => 2, 2, 2 and 1.

How can I do that? Isn't there a function in Elixir library?

`Enum.split` splits a list into 2 parts

update:

If I have 7 elements and I want to split them into 3 sub-lists, there should be created 3 sublists:

```
[[3 elements], [2 elements], [2 elements]]
```

Namely, I want to preserve all the elements

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. First, you state: `Or into 4 sub-lists => 2, 2, 2, 2 and 1`, you speak about 4 sublists but you enumerate 5. Second, the example for 7 elements as provided by you states that you want: `[[3 elements], [2 elements], [2 elements]]`, whereas there are other possibilities, such as `[[2 elements], [3 elements], [2 elements]]`, `[[1 elements], [3 elements], [3 elements]]`, `[[3 elements], [1 elements], [3 elements]]`, `[[2 elements], [2 elements], [3 elements]]` etc. Kindly clarify the criteria involved that would differentiate one from the other

Comment: @KevinJohnson 1) typo, should be 4 sub-lists; 2) a small sub-list should merge into the 1st sublist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could consider using [`Enum.chunk_every`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/4) to split the list into sublists of n amount elements each:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Enum.chunk_every(some_list, 2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

By calculating the total length of the list first:

```
total_length = length(some_list)
```

and dividing that number with the desired amount of parts giving you the length of each chunk:

```
desired_amount_of_sublists = 3
chunk_length = Integer.floor_div(total_length, desired_amount_of_sublists)
```

should allow you to arbitrarily chunk the list into as many parts you require:

```
Enum.chunk_every(some_list, chunk_length)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

In the case that you have a hard requirement to have each sublist be of exactly n elements, then you can pass in the option `:discard` to discard the last sublist if it is less than n elements:

```
Enum.chunk_every([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 2, 2, :discard)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

In the case that you have the hard requirement where you cannot discard any element and for instance you need the remainder elements to be incorporated with the first sublist, then you can do as follows:

Say that with the above you arrive at:

```
result_so_far = Enum.chunk_every([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
```

First reverse `result_so_far`, and take the first sublist thereof, which would be `[7]`, as follows:

`[last_sublist | other_sublists] = Enum.reverse(result_so_far)`

Then you check the length of `last_sublist`. If it corresponds to `chunk_length`, then you are fine, `result_so_far` has the desired result.
In the case it is smaller than `chunk_length`, you will need to incorporate its elements with the first sublist of `result_so_far`, which you can do as follows:
`[first_sublist | rest ] = Enum.reverse(other_sublists)`

`[Enum.concat(first_sublist, last_sublist) | rest]` should then render

`[[1, 2, 7], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`

Comment: First of all, I don't know how the size of each chunk. I know the amount of sublists.

Comment: Secondly, if I have 7 elements and wanted to split it into 3 sub-lists with 2 elements each, Enum.chunk_every would split it into 4 sub-lists ---> 2, 2, 2 and 1 ---> that's not what I want. I want 3, 2, 2 or 2, 2, 3

Comment: @Ivanari I updated the answer to provide you with a way to get the size of each chunk given the amount of sublists you desire.

Comment: Ok. see my 2nd comment

Comment: @Ivanari you could pass in option `:discard` to discard the last chunk if it is not of desired size. I will update

Comment: but i don't want to discard it, i want it to be merged with the 1st element

Comment: i want to preserve all the elements in created sub-lists

Comment: @Ivarani in that case, for a list of 7 elements you could remove the last element so you have a list of 6 elements + 1 extra on the side. You do the `Enum.chunk_every` for the list of 6 elements as described, and then you take the first sublist and add the extra element to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume we want 3 chunks:

```rb
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
chunk_count = 3
chunk_length =
  list
  |> Enum.count()
  |> div(chunk_count)


list
|> Enum.with_index() # to calculate position
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {e, i}, acc ->
     Map.update(acc, rem(div(i, chunk_length), chunk_count), [e], &([e | &1]))
   end)
|> Map.values()      # since we do need lists
|> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
#⇒ [[1, 2, 7], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

If lists in Elixir were to implement [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) behaviour, the code would be much simpler as we could use `Kernel.put_in/3`.

Comment: опять ты  пришёл и всех порвал

Answer (score 0):

Found this question, but none of the current answers worked for my use case, for which I wanted the group sizes to be as uniform as possible. For example:

```rb
Enum.to_list(1..100) |> chunk_uniformly(6) |> Enum.map(&length/1)

# desired result is [17, 17, 17, 17, 16, 16]
# current accepted answer returns [20, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]
```

Here's my eventual solution:

```rb
def chunk_uniformly(list, number_of_chunks) do
  len = length(list)

  optimal_chunk_size = div(len + number_of_chunks - 1, number_of_chunks)

  overspill = optimal_chunk_size * number_of_chunks - len

  {full_chunks, partial_chunks} =
    list
    |> Enum.split((number_of_chunks - overspill) * optimal_chunk_size)

  Enum.concat(
    full_chunks |> Enum.chunk_every(optimal_chunk_size),
    case partial_chunks do
      [] -> List.duplicate([], overspill)
      ls -> ls |> Enum.chunk_every(optimal_chunk_size - 1)
    end
  )
end
```

If, like in my use case, you're actually working from a maximum chunk size, you can get the number of chunks like this:

```rb
number_of_chunks = div(length(list) + max_chunk_size - 1, max_chunk_size)
```