# How to break collection up into smaller groups - Elixir

Tags: elixir

How to breakup this collection `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` into smaller groups?
to get this `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list into N parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345585/split-a-list-into-n-parts)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Enum.chunk_every/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2) to split it by chunks

```elixir
Enum.chunk_every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
#⇒ [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

or [`Enum.split/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split/2) to split it into a tuple containing two parts.

```elixir
Enum.split([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
#⇒ {[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]}
```